# Showing real-time temperature data using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, sensors

In my current project, I have to display real-time temperature data, coming from temperature sensor over network. We are thinking to solve this problem in the following way:

**Proposed Solution**: An `index.html` file (**the code is attached below**) will read temperature data from a `data.tsv`  file **periodically** (every 2-3 seconds) and  temperature sensor appends generated temperature data in `data.tsv`. So, every time, `index.html` file will display the updated result.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. The above proposed solution is correct? Could we have better solution/technology? Feel free to suggest other methods/technologies to address this problem.
2. If the above solution is correct, then how could I read the `data.tsv` file **periodically**?

> body{
>         font:10px sans-serif;
>       }
>       .axis path,
>       .axis line {
>         fill: none;
>         stroke: #000;
>         shape-rendering: crispEdges;
>       }
>
> ```
> .line {
>   fill: none;
>   stroke: steelblue;
>   stroke-width: 1.5px;
> }
> </style>
> <body>
>  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>
>   var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom:30, left:50},
>           width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
>           height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
>
>   var xColumn = "date"; 
>     var yColumn = "temperature";      
>
>   var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
>
>
>   var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
>   var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
>
>
>   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
>   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
>
>   var line = d3.svg.line()
>               .x(function(d) { return x(d[xColumn]);})
>               .y(function(d) { return y(d[yColumn]);});
>
>   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
>           .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
>           .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
>           .append("g")
>           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
>
>   d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data){
>       if(error) throw error;
>
>   data.forEach(function(d) {
>       d[xColumn]= parseDate(d[xColumn]);
>       d[yColumn] = +d[yColumn];
>   });
>
>   //Defining Min and max data
>   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d[xColumn];}));
>   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d[yColumn];}));
>
>   svg.append("g")
>       .attr("class","x axis")
>       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
>       .call(xAxis)
>           .append("text")
>           .text("TimeStamp");     
>
>   svg.append("g")
>       .attr("class", "y axis")
>       .call(yAxis)
>           .append("text")
>           .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
>           .attr("y",6)
>           .attr("dy", ".71em")
>           .style("text-anchor","end")
>           .text("Temperature");
>
>   svg.append("path")
>       .datum(data)
>       .attr("class", "line")
>       .attr("d", line);   
>   }); 
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your solution will be deployed, you might have to implement a small backend to serve your file. Ideally I'd implement a node backend with a socket to communicate with your client side. Pushing instead of polling. The approach you suggest will work, but it's not the most elegant/efficient, I'd say. To poll a file, a simple timeout would do the trick. Again, what you put in the timeout will depend on where your solution is.